# I want the Add Selling Rate modal to display when I click on the cancel button, instead it does not display it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When i click on the cancel button it should show the Add Selling Rate modal
here is my code for the cancelbutton event -

```
cancelSellingRate: function () {
                                SwitchModalOnSuccess();
                                sellingRateGridsVM.setProcessingStatusForSelectSellingRate(false);
                            }
```

How can i bring the previous model to display

I am trying to see how can i click on cancel and the model does not display